# Small p-values do not display in modelsummary output

Tags: r, modelsummary

I am comparing 4 regression outputs and am using the modelsummary package to tabulate and present the data.

Some of my p.values are *extremely* small (e.g. 2e-28) - and therefore essentially zero - but the output table displays "p =" rather than "p = 0".

I can't determine how to configure this.

My code is:

```
# Linear models summary - Stateline, Garland, Benban, Bungala

library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
# For tables
library(modelsummary)
library(kableExtra)
library(gt)

[Import data from CSVs]

# Processing and presenting models
# Info from https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html

# Define models

models <- list(
  "Stateline"     = lm(mean ~ 0 + buffer + Month + JulianDay + TimePeriod, data = stateline_data),
  "Garland"     = lm(mean ~ 0 +buffer + Month + JulianDay + TimePeriod, data = garland_data),
  "Benban"     = lm(mean ~ 0 + buffer + Month + JulianDay + TimePeriod, data = benban_data),
  "Bungala"     = lm(mean ~ 0 + buffer + Month + JulianDay + TimePeriod, data = bungala_data))

modelsummary(models,
             estimate = "{estimate}{stars}",
             statistic = c("conf.int",
                           "s.e. = {std.error}",
                           "t = {statistic}",
                           "p = {p.value}"), 
             fmt = 4,
             coef_rename = c("buffer" = "Buffer", "JulianDay" = "Julian Day", "TimePeriod2" = "Post-Construction"))
```

An example of the output:

[image]

I can display the full value using scientific notation but this makes the other data harder to interpret.

How can I either present the p-values are zero, or present just the p-values using scientific notation?

Comment: Does rounding/setting number of decimal digits with the `fmt` argument help? https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#output-print-and-save

Comment: It makes no difference - see comment on solution below, though.

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug which I think should be fixed now. The issue was the p value gets printed as `p = <0.001`, but `gt` intepreted this as the start of an HTML tag, which resulted in an empty string.

Install the latest `modelsummary` from Github:

```r
remotes::install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")
```

**Restart `R` completely**, then:

```
library(modelsummary)

x <- rnorm(1e6)
y <- x + rnorm(1e6, sd = .001)
mod <- lm(y ~ x)
modelsummary(mod, 
  output = "gt",
  statistic = c("SE = {std.error}", "p = {p.value}"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Vincent.  Sorry for the slow reply.  Using output = "gt" the issue is resolved.  I was (and am) using output = "filename.png", and here the issue persists.

Comment: I am getting this error, and I started using the package this week. NB my output is within the .Rmd file.

Comment: This should be fixed in the development version on Github. Please follow the installation instructions in the post and try again.